# How to inspected the file system to investigate if the image was uploaded

Tags: files

After I upload an image, I see blank image. How can I inspect the file system to investigate if the image was uploaded or not?

Thanks,
M

Comment: How are you uploading this image? Through a node (field api) or through different means?

Comment: Admin > Add contents > I have an image field. Click Upload > Browse to the image file.

Comment: do you get any console errors when viewing the page, or log errors when uploading?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not appearing after an upload via the field api then you might want to check if your files directory is writable by apache. Typically this would be sites/default/files.

NOTE: sites/default/files should ONLY be writable by apache and nothing else.

Comment: I just right click the blank image > Properties > got the url of the image. While I logged in as admin, I pasted the image url in address bar, it says I don't have permission. After that, I did go to admin > people > Permission > I see all check boxes marked for admin. I am not sure why I would not have permission.  I also went to admin > report > status report> it says "File system Writable (public download method) "

Comment: @KaimeiWang Are you getting a Drupal permissions error, an Apache permissions error, or something else? Have you checked to make sure your webserver user can read the upload directory? On some platforms, it may also need execute permissions.

Comment: After I logged in as admin, in the address bar, i pasted the image url. I get the below error. I dont know what kind of error it is: "Access denied 

You are not authorized to access this page. " Also, I am not sure how I can check if webserver user can read the upload directory. Please help.